# Solving the exponential Diophantine equation $2^{m+1} = zk + 1$ where $m,k,z \in Z$ for a given very large $z$

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

I am working on a problem where I have ended with an exponential Diophantine equation of the form

$$2^{m+1} = zk + 1$$

where $m,k,z \in Z$ for a given very large $z$ (i.e., factoring $z$ is practically hard).

Are there any techniques I could use to solve this?

Comment: My two cents : If you can't easily find a factor of $z$, $z$ must be odd (otherwise $2$ is an easy factor of $z$), and put $z_2=\frac{z-1}{2}$. Iterate on $z_2$, and you get a decreasing sequence $(z_n)$, stop when it reaches an easily factorable number. Then, compute $2^{z_n}(mod \ z)$  starting with the largest values of $n$. It might lead you to finding the order of $2$ modulo $z$.

Comment: $z$ and $k$ are odd without a question.

Answer (score -1):

Comment:

I think all Mersenne numbers ($2^k-1$) which are not primes can give a family of solutions in $mathbb N$. For example Mersenne number $M_{11}=2047=23\times 89$ which gives:

$(n. z, k)=(10, 23, 89)$